# Show/hide QDockWidget?

Tags: qt, visibility

I have a dock widget, now I want to add a "Window" menu to show/hide the widget. Easy enough to do with

```
showPropWinAct = new QAction(tr("&Properties"), this);
showPropWinAct->setStatusTip(tr("Show properties window"));
showPropWinAct->setCheckable(true);
connect(showPropWinAct, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), propertiesWindow, SLOT(setVisible(bool)));
```

The problem is when the user clicks the [x] on the widget, the `showPropWinAct` doesn't get toggled. How can I listen for this event, and toggle the action properly, without firing off a 2nd setVisible signal (one from the close event presumably, and one from the `connect` above)?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Instead of creating a new action, simply get the action from the QDockWidget itself and use that. It'll take care of state for you:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdockwidget.html#toggleViewAction

`QAction * QDockWidget::toggleViewAction () const`

"Returns a checkable action that can be used to show or close this dock widget.

The action's text is set to the dock widget's window title.
"

Comment: Hah! Brilliant. Knew there had to be a better way to do this. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Any way to do this in the designer? Currently I just use `void MainWindow::on_dockWindow_visibilityChanged(bool visible) { ui->actionDockWindowToggle->setChecked(visible); }` and then `setShown()` in the action `on_toggled()` slot. It works well enough and is only two lines of code, but if there's a way to use `toggleViewAction()` in the designer that'd be nice!

Comment: @Timmmm [Here](https://ulm-iqo.github.io/qudi-generated-docs/html-docs/viewmenu.html) it says how to do it in the designer. It doesn't use the QDockWidget's own `toggleViewAction`, though.

Comment: I was struggling with this today, this is such a simple solution, thanks!